# How to sort a list of nested dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [
   { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
   { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }
]
```

I was hoping to sort the list based on those integer values with **different** keys 'aaa', bbb', 'ccc', etc.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary) but the keys are consistent to this problem.

Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: My desired output is:

```
sorted_list = [
       { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } },
       { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
       { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
       { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } }
]
```

Comment: Do the dictionaries always have only one key/value pair? If so, sort by the fist item in `values()`.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the expected result for this input? Which key/value pair will you care about from the nested dictionary, and how do you know?

Comment: @MarkM yes. In my case, the key is 'frame' and its value is a dictionary.

Comment: Anyway, the approach is the same as in the linked answer. You need to be able to write a function that tells you a value that corresponds to each item of `mylist`, and then you will sort according to those values, by using `key=`.

Comment: "In my case, the key is 'frame' and its value is a dictionary" No; we're talking about *that dictionary which is the value*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel please see the edited question

Comment: Okay, so you want to put `{ 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }` first because the `72` value associated with the `'ddd'` key is the largest one found, right? *How do you know the `'ddd'` key is the one you want to look at, and not any of the other keys in `{ 'ddd': 72 }`*? Like, in the example you showed, there aren't any other keys. If there were, it obviously would be a problem. That's why you were asked to clarify.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry for missing those important details, the keys are unique. Meaning, there is only one 'ddd' key in the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = sorted(mylist, key=lambda k: -list(k["frame"].values())[0])
print(mylist)
```

Prints:

```
[{'frame': {'ddd': 72}}, 
 {'frame': {'aaa': 50}}, 
 {'frame': {'ccc': 23}}, 
 {'frame': {'bbb': 12}}]
```

Comment: Instead of negating the value returned by the `lambda`, you can also use `reverse=True` in the `sorted` call. Like: `sorted(mylist, key=lambda k: list(k["frame"].values())[0], reverse=True)`. This has the advantage that it also works for `key` functions that compute a non-numeric (but still sortable) result (such as a string).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with a `lambda` for the `key` which just returns the first value stored in the `dict` under the `'frame'` key.

We get the first value by using [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with [**`iter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter). This avoids creating a new `list` object.

We also pass the `reverse` parameter as `True`, so we get biggest numbers first.
:

```
>>> mylist = [
...    { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
...    { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } },
...    { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
...    { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }
... ]

>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: next(iter(d['frame'].values())), reverse=True)
[{'frame': {'ddd': 72}},
 {'frame': {'aaa': 50}},
 {'frame': {'ccc': 23}},
 {'frame': {'bbb': 12}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak to the answer in that question gets you this which works.

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda k: k['frame'][list(k['frame'].keys())[0]], reverse=True)
```

Essentially it just goes down into the list, To then sort by the values. Set `reverse` to True to get it to reverse the list.